# VBA - assigning the calculated value to a cell in different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a code to calculate a cost from one sheet of a workbook. 
after calculating I want that value to appear on another sheet of same workbook

```
Sub cost()

    Dim irow As Integer
    Dim pointer1 As Single
    Dim Kgl_PG_Campaign As Single
    Kgl_PG_Campaign = 0
    pointer1 = 0
    irow = 2
    Do Until Cells(irow, 3).Value = ""
        If Worksheets("ws2").Cells(irow, 11).Value = "Kagal" And Cells(irow, 12).Value = "PG" And Cells(irow, 24).Value = "Campaign" Then
            pointer1 = Cells(irow, 29).Value
            Kgl_PG_Campaign = Kgl_PG_Campaign + pointer1
        End If
    irow = irow + 1
    MsgBox Kgl_PG_Campaign
    Worksheets("COPQ_online").Range("C7").Value = Kgl_PG_Campaign
    Loop


End Sub
```

`Error - run time error 9 - script out of range`.

Please help

Comment: When you step through the code, where does it fail? Do all of the sheets exist in the workbook?

Comment: As for your error, there seems to be an error with some named reference. Please check if the worksheet-names are correct. See also [Subscript out of range (Error 9)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519(v=vs.60).aspx). Also you should have `Worksheets("ws2").Cells(irow, ##)` in each `And`-part of your `If`-statement and in the line `pointer1 = Worksheets("ws2").Cells(irow, 29).Value`. Without a worksheet reference, you will be referencing the ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: The following line is causing the problem Worksheets("COPQ_online").Range("C7").Value = Kgl_PG_Campaign upto MsgBox Kgl_PG_Campaign code is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you are after something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub cost()
    Dim irow As Long
    Dim Kgl_PG_Campaign As Single

    Kgl_PG_Campaign = 0
    irow = 2
    With Worksheets("ws2")
        Do Until Cells(irow, 3).Value = ""
            If .Cells(irow, 11).Value = "Kagal" And .Cells(irow, 12).Value = "PG" And .Cells(irow, 24).Value = "Campaign" Then
                Kgl_PG_Campaign = Kgl_PG_Campaign + .Cells(irow, 29).Value
            End If
            irow = irow + 1
            MsgBox Kgl_PG_Campaign
        Loop
    End With
    Worksheets("COPQ_online").Range("C7").Value = Kgl_PG_Campaign
End Sub
```

where I assumed that you want to write in `Worksheets("COPQ_online")` after you looped through "ws2" column "C" cells from row three down to the one preceeding the first empty cell

Comment: where I assumed that you want to write in Worksheets("COPQ_online") after you looped through "ws2" column "C" cells from row two down to the one preceeding the first empty cell

Comment: instead of three down its 2 down, this code is giving the same error  in line Worksheets("COPQ_online").Range("C7").Value = Kgl_PG_Campaign the same error giving in my code.            upto msg box both the codes are working fine.

Comment: I would also like to mention if I am changing the worksheet to the current sheet(ws2) instead of "COPQ_online" code is working fine.